# How to develop Unlock Pattern for Android App

Tags: android

I want to develop unlock pattern for my android app.
Any suggestions on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend a View, override `onDraw` to display the touch points, override `onTouchEvent` to handle user input

Use:

`canvas.drawBitmap` to draw the graphical touch points

`path.lineTo` to draw the lines between touch points